# Qt.Signals&Slots.ConnectingProblem

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I'm experiencing some troubles with Qt's "signals and slots" mechanism. I have something like that(NOTE: this is only quick example):

```
class A : public QGLWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

private: 
int *m_ptr;

public slots:
void addPtr(int *ptr){m_ptr=ptr;}                ///Breakpoint here
};

class B: public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

private:
A* m_AclassObject;

public:
B()
{
m_AclassObject=new A();
this->connect(this,SIGNAL(emitAddPtr(int *ptr)),
              m_AclassObject,SLOT(m_AclassObject->addPtr(int *ptr)));
}
void addPtr(int *p)
{
emit emitAddPtr(p);
}
signals:
void emitAddPtr(int *p)
};
```

I'm using Qt v.4.8.0 and Visual Studio 2010. Code compiles without any mistakes and no troubles at runtime, but it seems because  it's just don't work :).  My problem is the following: in debug i can't enter the class A slot with something like that:

```
int k=2;
int *p=&k;
B B_obj;
B_obj.addPtr(p);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is when you connect the signal to the slot. Try this instead:

```
this->connect(this,SIGNAL(emitAddPtr(int *)),
          m_AclassObject,SLOT(addPtr(int *)));
```

Also, I wouldn't really recommend using signals/slots in this particular case, since there's no need for them. It would make more sense just to call `A::addPtr()` inside of your `B::addPtr()` function. Of course, if your example is just a contrived one, then disregard this suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Tried to change that. Still the same result. =\ Thanks for suggestion, i think i'll like that. But still can't understand what's wrong with the slot.

Comment: @SergeyT Try the edited version. Note the lack of variable name for the int pointer.

Comment: Hm,Thanks, i've finally entered the slot-function! :) after deleting names of the args!

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong:

```
this->connect(this,SIGNAL(emitAddPtr(int *ptr)),
          m_AclassObject,SLOT(m_AclassObject->addPtr(int *ptr)));
```

you want something like this:

```
this->connect(this,SIGNAL(emitAddPtr(int *ptr)),
          m_AclassObject,SLOT(addPtr(int *ptr)));
```

Comment: This is wrong: it includes the variable names in the connection string, which is a common mistake and never works. All `int *ptr` should be changed to `int *` in the SIGNAL and SLOT parameters.